# I have a warning "passing argument 2 of 'bins' make integer from pointer without cast"

Tags: c, arguments, warnings

In a binary search, I have the warning I wrote in the title:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int bins(int, int, int, int);/*this function do a binary search*/

    int main()
    {
        int n, low, high, v[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        low=0;high=11;
        printf("please enter the num you want to find\n:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d", bins(n, v, low, high));
    return 0;
    }
    int bins(int n, int v[], int low, int high)
    {
        int mid;
        if(low>high)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        mid=(high+low)/2;
        if(v[mid]>n)
        {
            bins(n, v, low, high-mid);
        }
        if(v[mid]<n)
        {
            bins(n, v, low+mid, high);
        }
        return mid;
    }
```

Considering that the array is organized.

I have a warning "passing argument 2 of 'bins' make integer from pointer without cast".

Comment: Do you have the function declared before you use it?

Comment: Your function prototype, `int bins(int, int, int, int);` is different from the definition, in which the second argument is `int[]`.

Comment: `int bins(int, int, int, int);` --> `int bins(int, int *, int, int);`

Comment: Read the [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book

Answer (score 0):

The head of the defintion of `bins`:

```
int bins(int n, int v[], int low, int high) { ...
```

is different to the function´s prototype:

```
int bins(int, int, int, int);      /*this function do a binary search*/
```

at the second parameter definition.

In the former the second parameter is of type pointer to `int`.
In the latter the second parameter is of type `int`.

There is a mismatch.

---

Correct the second parameter at the function´s prototype:

```
int bins(int, int[], int, int);      /*this function do a binary search*/
                 |
                Here
```

and the code compiles without warnings.

---

Side note:

The algorithm in `bins()` seems faulty. It will always return `mid = 5`, no matter what `n` is, because `mid` is only assigned by `(high+low) / 2`.